# How do I unload images in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to rename an image currently being viewed in a PyGame window (same program), and since that isn't really a good idea, I had it rename at the end of the program.
However, it still gives me the error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being
used by another process
```

I tried "quitting" (un-initializing) the PyGame and the display, but it still says that it cannot rename the file with the error above.

Is there a way to unload images? Is that what I need to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Could there be a `close` method anywhere?

Comment: I looked. I am able to quit all the PyGame methods, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting a file object and using that instead, for example:

```
f = open('myfile.png')
pygame.image.load(f)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `unload()` , It's new in pygame ver 2.0.0