# How to remove an image in pygame?

Tags: python, image, pygame

I'm working on a game and I have some problems working with images. 
I have loaded a few images . loading them and using `screen.blit()` was okay like below:

```
img1 = pygame.image.load("leaf.png")
img1 = pygame.transform.scale(img1, (25,25))
leaf = img1.get_rect()
leaf.x = random.randint(0, 570)
leaf.y =  random.randint(0, 570)
```

but I don't know how to remove them in an if statement like this for example:

```
if count == 1:
...
```

and I though maybe there is no way and I should draw a rectangle on the image to disappear it. Also I don't know how to use `screen.fill()` while I don't want the other images to get disappeared. Is there any other way?

Comment: yes, usually you redraw the whole screen for every frame

Comment: Here is an example to use file.close() as a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633320/how-do-i-unload-images-in-pygame

Comment: @pypalms: what???

Comment: Do what hop suggests, clear the screen with `screen.fill(color)` and then redraw all images that should be visible. `color` can be a tuple or list with 3 or 4 elements or a [`pygame.Color`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/color.html) object. @pypalms' linked answer is misleading.

Answer (score 4):

You can fill individual images, since they are pygame Surfaces.

First, what I would do is I would put something like this after defining the leaf's x/y:

`leaf.image = img1`

Then, I would create a color variable called `transparent`:

`transparent = (0, 0, 0, 0)`

The first 3 numbers, as you might know, represent RGB color values. The last number is the alpha (transparency) value of a color. 0 is completely invisible.

Finally, I would add this code to make the leaf completely transparent:

`leaf.image.fill(transparent)`

This makes the leaf transparent without making every other image in your window disappear. Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `screen.fill()` for that following is an example that shows how to do it:

```
import pygame
import time
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
screen.fill((255,255,255))#white
img = pygame.image.load('img.png')
img = pygame.transform.scale(img,(25,25))
img2 = pygame.image.load('bubble.png')
img2 = pygame.transform.scale(img,(25,25))
screen.blit(img,(250,250))
screen.blit(img2,(350,250))
pygame.display.update()
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        screen.fill((255,255,255))
        screen.blit(img2, (350, 250))
        pygame.display.update()
        time.sleep(1)
        screen.blit(img, (255,255))
        pygame.display.update()
```

for making any type of animation om pygame you have to redraw every thing including the background