# deleting an image on pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I was just wondering if anyone knew how to delete a picture in pygame once the image collides with another. Right now, my the battery and the e-waste is colliding together and when it does, an explosion happens but that doesn't occur at the correct place yet. My goal is to delete the e-waste image once it collides with the battery. I'm not sure how to do that so can anyone please help? Thanks

````
import pygame
pygame.init()
import random
SIZE = (width, height) = (1000, 700) #Screen Size
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)


#Defining Colours
GREEN = (0,255,0)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
GREY = (48,48,48)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
YELLOW = (246, 255, 112)
BLUE = (0, 9, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)


#======= initialize Variables =======

in_game = False
shipEats = 0
score = 0
health = 100


#Ship
x_ship_pos = 500 # ship x coord
y_ship_pos = 600 # ship y coord
x_ship_speed = 0 # move ship x coord by x
y_ship_speed = 0 # move ship y coord by y
direction = 360 #Ship faces up


#Battery
is_battery_on_screen = False
x_battery_pos = 0
y_battery_pos = 0
battery_direction = "UP"


#E-Waste
xWastePos = random.randint(0, 300)
yWastePos = random.randint(0, 580)

xWaste2 = random.randint(330, 600)
yWaste2 = random.randint(0, 580)

xWaste3 = random.randint(630, 990)
yWaste3 = random.randint(0, 580)

#Ewaste Explosion
xExplosionPos = xWastePos
yExplosionPos = yWastePos


#Star
xStarPos = xWastePos
yStarPos = yWastePos


#LOADING ALL IMAGES AND SOUNDS FOR GAME
backgroundImage = pygame.image.load("spaceBackground.jpg")
mainscreenImage = pygame.image.load("galaxyy.jpg")
shipImage = pygame.image.load("spaceship.png")
batteryImage = pygame.image.load("battery.png")
ewasteImage = pygame.image.load("ewaste.png")
explosionImage = pygame.image.load("explosion.png")
starImage = pygame.image.load("star.png")
ewaste2Image = pygame.image.load("ewaste2.png")
ewasteImage = pygame.transform.scale(ewasteImage, (340, 150))
batteryImage = pygame.transform.scale(batteryImage, (30, 40))

#------------------------Functions------------------------
def drawScene(screen, mx, my, button): #Draws game screen with space background
    screen.blit(backgroundImage, (0,0))


def display_main_screen(): #MAIN SCREEN IN PYGAME
    screen.blit(mainscreenImage, (0,0)) 

    screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(ewaste2Image, (180, 200)), (60, 340))
    screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(ewaste2Image, (180, 200)), (760, 340))

    title = font.render("E-Waste Exploder", 1, WHITE)
    screen.blit(title, (220,160,400,100)) #Displays Text      

    leaderBtn = pygame.Rect(30, 550, 300,120) #Leaderboard Button
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLUE, leaderBtn)
    leaderBtn = font3.render("Leaderboard", 1, WHITE)
    screen.blit(leaderBtn, (50,590,400,100)) #Displays Text    

    instrBtn = pygame.Rect(350, 550, 300,120) #How to play Button
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLUE, instrBtn)
    instrBtn = font3.render("How to play", 1, WHITE)
    screen.blit(instrBtn, (380,590,400,100)) #Displays Text

    quitBtn = pygame.Rect(670, 550, 300,120) #Quit Button
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLUE, quitBtn)
    quitBtn = font3.render("Quit", 1, WHITE)
    screen.blit(quitBtn, (760,590,400,100)) #Displays Text 

    playBtn = pygame.Rect(280, 410, 450,120) #Play Game Button
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLUE, playBtn)
    playBtn = font.render("Play", 1, WHITE)
    screen.blit(playBtn, (420,440,400,100)) #Displays Text   


def gamePage(): #Game page
    drawScene(screen, mx, my, button) #Draws a new screen


#-------------DRAWING ALL OBJECTS FOR GAME-------------

def draw_ship(): 
    global shipImage, direction
    # VR - using a different variable, so that every time through here we remember the direction of the original
    newImage = pygame.transform.rotate(shipImage, direction)
    screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(newImage, (100, 100)), (x_ship_pos, y_ship_pos)) #SPACESHIP 


def draw_explosivebattery(): 
    if is_battery_on_screen: 
        newImage = pygame.transform.rotate(batteryImage, direction)
        screen.blit(newImage, (x_battery_pos, y_battery_pos)) #BATTERY THAT SHOOTS 


def drawEwaste(): #Piles of e-waste displaying in game 
    global xWastePos, yWastePos
    screen.blit(ewasteImage, (xWastePos, yWastePos)) #EWASTE
    yWastePos += 15 #Speed of e-waste yPos
    if yWastePos > height: #Makes e-waste generate randomly from the top going vertically down
        xWastePos = random.randint(0, 500)
        yWastePos = 0 
    return

if xWastePos < 0 or xWastePos > 1000 or yWastePos < 0 or yWastePos > 700: #remove ewaste if off screen
    drawScene()


def drawStars():
    screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(starImage, (30, 30)), (xStarPos, yStarPos))


def drawExplosion():
    screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(explosionImage, (200, 200)), (xExplosionPos, yExplosionPos))
    #pygame.mixer.Sound.play(explosionSound)



#~~~~~~~~~~MOVING OBJECTS AND RESETTING POSITIONS~~~~~~~~~~
def move_ship(): #Moving ship
    global x_ship_pos, x_ship_speed, y_ship_pos, y_ship_speed
    x_ship_pos += x_ship_speed
    if x_ship_pos < -25: #Making sure spaceship doesn't go off screen
        x_ship_pos = -25
    elif x_ship_pos > 925:
        x_ship_pos = 925


    y_ship_pos += y_ship_speed
    if y_ship_pos < 0: #Making sure spaceship doesn't go off screen
        y_ship_pos = 0
    elif y_ship_pos > 600:
        y_ship_pos = 600


def move_battery(): #Moving battery
    global x_battery_pos, y_battery_pos, battery_direction, is_battery_on_screen  #GLOBAL VARIABLES
    if is_battery_on_screen:
        if battery_direction == "UP":
            y_battery_pos -= 70 #How fast the battery moves
        elif battery_direction == "DOWN":
            y_battery_pos += 70
        elif battery_direction == "RIGHT":
            x_battery_pos += 70
        elif battery_direction == "LEFT":
            x_battery_pos -= 70

        if x_battery_pos < 0 or x_battery_pos > 1000 or y_battery_pos < 0 or y_battery_pos > 700: #remove battery if off screen
            is_battery_on_screen = False

#--------CHECKING COLLISIONS--------


def ewasteCollision(battery, ewaste): #If battery hits ewaste
    global yWastePos
    if battery.colliderect(ewaste):
        #addEwaste()
        yWastePos += 1 #DOESN"T WORK
        return True
    False


#--------Defning fonts and buttons--------

#Fonts
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Courier", 100) #Font for titles
font2 = pygame.font.SysFont("Courier", 30) #Small Font 
font3 = pygame.font.SysFont("Courier", 60) #Font for small titles


#Defining Buttons
playBtn = pygame.Rect(280, 410, 450,120) #Play Game Button
instrBtn = pygame.Rect(350, 550, 300,120) #Instructions Button
quitBtn = pygame.Rect(680, 550, 300,120) #Quit Button
leaderBtn = pygame.Rect(30, 550, 300,120) #Leaderboard Button
mainMenuBtn = pygame.Rect(870, 20, 120,30) #mainMenuBtn


running = True
myClock = pygame.time.Clock()
mx = my = 0


display_main_screen() #Calling main screen function


#==========GAME LOOP==========

while running:
    button = 0
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False  
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_pos = event.pos #Gets mouse position
            if in_game == False:
                if playBtn.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                    gamePage()
                    in_game = True              
                elif quitBtn.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                    running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                direction = 0
                y_ship_speed = -20 #Spaceship speed
                if is_battery_on_screen == False:
                    battery_direction = "UP" #Saves direction as up
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_ship_speed = 20 #Spaceship speed
                direction = 180
                if is_battery_on_screen == False:
                    battery_direction = "DOWN" #Saves direction as down
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_ship_speed = -20 #Spaceship speed
                direction = 90
                if is_battery_on_screen == False:
                    battery_direction = "LEFT" #Saves direction as left
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_ship_speed = 20 #Spaceship speed
                direction = 270
                if is_battery_on_screen == False:
                    battery_direction = "RIGHT" #Saves direction as right

            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if is_battery_on_screen == False: #Shoots battery
                    is_battery_on_screen = True
                    x_battery_pos = x_ship_pos + 32
                    y_battery_pos = y_ship_pos + 26

            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                in_game = False
                display_main_screen() #Goes back to main menu

            if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                gamePage()
                in_game = True

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_ship_speed = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_ship_speed = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_ship_speed = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_ship_speed = 0  

    if in_game:
        #Calling action functions
        move_ship()
        move_battery()

        #Clearing the screen
        drawScene(screen, mx, my, button)

        #drawing objects to the screen
        draw_ship()
        draw_explosivebattery()
        drawEwaste()

        if is_battery_on_screen == True: #Collision with battery and ewaste
            batteryRect = pygame.Rect(x_battery_pos, y_battery_pos, batteryImage.get_width(), batteryImage.get_height()) #Dimensions of battery
            ewasteRect = pygame.Rect(xWastePos + 100, yWastePos, 150, 120) #Dimensions of ewaste
            if ewasteCollision(batteryRect, ewasteRect) == True: #If its true, ewaste explodes and disappears
                is_battery_on_screen = False
                drawExplosion()
                drawStars() #Stars appear for user to collect 

    pygame.display.flip()

    myClock.tick(120)

pygame.quit()```
````

Comment: [mcve] especially minimal please!

Comment: Hello, Amanda. This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50747882/how-to-remove-an-image-in-pygame/50867526

Comment: Next time when you post questions, make sure you see if anyone else has asked the question.

Comment: Oh I saw that and I've tried the code but it doesn't work

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255038/how-do-i-delete-an-image-after-a-collision-in-pygame

Comment: It also asks about how to remove an image after collision

Comment: `if ... == False:` should be `if ... is False:`, but most of the time it should simply be written `if not ... :`.

Comment: @AtticusDenewmont The issue is completely different. Next time before you mention about duplicates, read both questions (not just the title).

Comment: in `ewasteCollision` you forgot `return` in last line - it has to be `return False` instead of `False`

Comment: maybe you should check collision before you draw object and then draw object or draw explosion. In current code you first draw object then you check collision and draw explosion but you can't remove object - you would have to redraw all elements in window without objects.

Comment: if you would use Class then you could keep all objects on list and use `object.draw()` for every element on list to draw them. And then you can remove element from list to skip drawing it. But again you would have to check all colisions before you draw all elements.

Comment: BTW: you don't have to create again and again `Rect()` for all elements. For buttons you should create `playbtn = Rect()` only once and later use `playbtn` all time withouth using again `playbtn = Rect()` For other object you should also keep size and position in `batery_rect = Rect()` and change `batery_rect.x` `batery_rect.y` instead of recreating `Rect()`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it but you should check collsion before drawing and use result to draw objects or explosion

```
if in_game:
    #Calling action functions
    move_ship()
    move_battery()

    #Clearing the screen
    drawScene(screen, mx, my, button)

    #drawing objects to the screen
    draw_ship()

    if is_battery_on_screen == True: 
        batteryRect = pygame.Rect(x_battery_pos, y_battery_pos, batteryImage.get_width(), batteryImage.get_height()) #Dimensions of battery
        ewasteRect = pygame.Rect(xWastePos + 100, yWastePos, 150, 120) #Dimensions of ewaste

        if ewasteCollision(batteryRect, ewasteRect) == True: #If its true, ewaste explodes and disappears
            is_battery_on_screen = False
            drawExplosion()
            drawStars() #Stars appear for user to collect
        else:                
            draw_explosivebattery()
            drawEwaste()
```

---

**BTW:**

You should keep size and position in `Rect()` and change `rect.x` `rect.y` instead of recreating again and again `Rect()`.

You could also separate moves, collisions and draws.

Example:

```
battery_rect = pygame.Rect(x_battery_pos, y_battery_pos, batteryImage.get_width(), batteryImage.get_height()) #Dimensions of battery
ewaste_rect = pygame.Rect(xWastePos, yWastePos, 150, 120) #Dimensions of ewaste
is_battery_on_screen = True
is_ewaste_on_screen = True
is_explosion_on_screen = False
is_stars_on_screen = False

# in mainloop

if in_game:

    # --- moves --- (without collisions and draws)

    move_ship()

    if is_battery_on_screen: 
        move_battery()

    if is_ewaste_on_screen:
        ewaste_rect.x += 100 # move without creating again `Rect()`

    # --- collisions --- (without moves and draws)

    if is_battery_on_screen and is_ewaste_on_screen: 
        if ewaste_collision(battery_rect, ewaste_rect):
            is_battery_on_screen = False
            is_ewaste_on_screen = False
            is_explosion_on_screen = True
            is_stars_on_screen = True

    # --- draws --- (without moves and collisions)

    draw_scene(screen, mx, my, button)
    draw_ship()

    if is_battery_on_screen: 
        draw_explosivebattery()

    if is_ewaste_on_screen:
        draw_ewaste()

    if is_explosion_on_screen:
        draw_explosion()

    if is_stars_on_screen:
        draw_stars()
```

---

**BTW:** using `Rect()` to keep positions you can easily center text on button and you don't have to calculate it manually.

```
text = font.render(....)
text_rect = text.get_rect()

text_rect.center = button_rect.center

pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLUE, button_rect)
screen.blit(text, text_rect)
```

Frankly, at start you could generate surface with button and text and later only blit it without generating button again and again.